# on load event add images to different classes

Tags: jquery, html, css

i want to add images into different classes on load of images. 
this is fiddle .
http://jsfiddle.net/simmi_simmi123/Kxfg7/2/

```
<img src="http://placehold.it/10x60" /><br />
<img src="http://placehold.it/20x50" /><br />
<img src="http://placehold.it/30x40" /><br />
<img src="http://placehold.it/40x30" /><br />
<img src="http://placehold.it/50x20" /><br />
<img src="http://placehold.it/60x10" /><br />


$(function(){
    $('img').addClass('brdr1');
});
```

In this i am adding all images into `brdr1` one but i want to add 3 images in `brdr1` and remaining in `brdr2`

How to do this.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Working demo :  http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/Kxfg7/8/

```
$(function(){
   $('img:lt(3)').addClass('brdr1');
   $('img:gt(2)').addClass('brdr2');
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/

http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/

Answer (score 1):

add class to specify which images to apply which class

## **HTML**

```
<img class="b1" src="http://placehold.it/10x60" /><br />
<img class="b1" src="http://placehold.it/20x50" /><br />
<img class="b1" src="http://placehold.it/30x40" /><br />
<img  class="b2" src="http://placehold.it/40x30" /><br />
<img  class="b2" src="http://placehold.it/50x20" /><br />
<img  class="b2" src="http://placehold.it/60x10" /><br />
```

## **CSS**

```
.brdr{border:1px solid red}
.brdr11{border:1px solid blue}
```

## **jQuery**

```
$(function(){
    $('.b1').addClass('brdr');
    $('.b2').addClass('brdr1');
});
```

Working Demo http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/Kxfg7/5/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#theDiv').prepend('<img id="theImg" src="theImg.png" />')
```

Answer (score 0):

Give **b1** and **b2**(classes) for respective images then,
just add proper css classes for respective images like this on `onload()` in jquery like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.b1').addClass('brdr1');
  $('.b2').addClass('brdr2');
});
```

Comment: @xpy:Thats a shocker bro, i never realised it , thanks alot man :)